# How to convert C# code to create an auth key into PHP

Tags: c#, php, datetime, int64

I have code to generate an auth key in C# that looks like:

```
    public string generateToken()
    {
        byte[] time = BitConverter.GetBytes(DateTime.UtcNow.ToBinary());
        byte[] key = Guid.NewGuid().ToByteArray();
        string token = Convert.ToBase64String(time.Concat(key).ToArray());

        return token;
    }
```

An auth key looks like this: `21VMky3f10ik7t5IeGKCSrA+MO10rN2N`
And code to decode it that looks like this:

```
    public bool decodeToken(string token)
    {
        byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(token);
        DateTime when = DateTime.FromBinary(BitConverter.ToInt64(data, 0));
        if (when < DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(-24))
        {
            //token is more than 24 hours old
            return false;
        } else
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

How would I translate the `decodeToken` function into a PHP function so I can verify the token on a server.

My current PHP code is as follows:

```
$decoded = base64_decode($token);
$rawBytes = "";
foreach(str_split($decoded) as $byte)
{
    $rawBytes .= ' ' . sprintf("%08b", ord($byte));
}

$new = unpack("q",$rawBytes);

$time = ticks_to_time($new[1]);
return date("F j Y g:i:s A T", $time);
```

$new[1] = `3544386994072269088` which is then turned into a datetime giving:

```
September 18 11232 6:16:47 PM UTC
```

This is not correct and I don't know how to fix it

Thanks!

Comment: show us your php code and the issues that you are having.

Comment: @Vidal I have added the code :)

Comment: on this line **$time = ticks_to_time($new[1]);** what is the contents of the time variable ?

Comment: @Vidal $new[1] is `3544386994072269088 ` - An auth key also looks like this: 21VMky3f10ik7t5IeGKCSrA+MO10rN2N

Answer (score 0):

The Int64 value can be determined directly after the base64_decode with unpack.
int64 is a 64-bit signed integer that encodes the Kind property into a 2-bit field and the Ticks property into a 62-bit field.
The ticks must be filtered out using a mask. The ticks are then converted into the linux timestamp.

```
$token = "21VMky3f10ik7t5IeGKCSrA+MO10rN2N";

$decoded = base64_decode($token);

$decArr = unpack("q",$decoded);
$int64 = $decArr[1]; //5248909277561378267 = 2 bit kind and 62 bit ticks

$ticks = ($int64 & 0x3fffffffffffffff);

$linuxTs = $ticks/10000000 - 62135596800;

echo gmdate("Y-m-d H:i:s",$linuxTs);
//2020-04-12 22:05:13
```